# Proper shebang for Swift script targeting iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bash, shebang

I'm trying to set the right shebang to perform a Swift script for iOS

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator swift -target x86_64-apple-ios12.1-simulator

import Foundation
import UIKit

print("Hello, World!")
```

but it's not working. 
when I run my script:

`./myScript.swift`

I read this in the terminal:

`<unknown>:0: error: could not load the swift standard library`

I've been trying different shebang settings to make it work 
`#!/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk -target x86_64-apple-ios12.1-simulator` but still no success.

at last but not least it's important to run an iOS version because I need to import UIKit.

Thanx

/// myScript fullversion:

```
#!/usr/bin/swift

import Foundation
import UIKit

public class FileSystem {

    @discardableResult init() {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        do {
            let resourceKeys: [URLResourceKey] = [.creationDateKey, .isDirectoryKey]
            let documentsURL = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
            guard let enumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(at: URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsURL),
                                                                  includingPropertiesForKeys: resourceKeys,
                                                                  options: [.skipsHiddenFiles], errorHandler: { (url, error) -> Bool in
                                                                    print("directoryEnumerator error at \(url): ", error)
                                                                    exit(1)
            }) else {
                print("error, can't find directory")
                exit(1)
            }

            for case let fileURL as URL in enumerator {
                let file = fileURL.lastPathComponent
                print(file)
                // check if file is a class that conforms to protocol X 
            }
        }
    }
}

FileSystem()
```

`./myScript.swift:4:8: error: no such module 'UIKit'`

Comment: “it's important to run an iOS version” makes no sense, you’re running on a Mac. iOS can’t run scripts

Comment: so there's no way to perform a script routine in UIKit out of Xcode?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "perform a script routine in UIKit," but iOS doesn't support shell scripts at all. That has has nothing to with UIKit. If you use UIKit on Mac (as of 10.15), then you should be able to import UIKit in a script (though I'm very curious why you want to).

Comment: On linux, the shebang line is limited both in width and in the number of words. I don't know if MacOS has the same kind of restrictions: I don't know what the equivalent of the `execve(2)` man page is on the mac.

Comment: @AntonioJunior The real issue here is that it is completely unclear what you're really trying to do. `print` is hardly a compelling example.

Comment: @RobNapier I want to iterate all UIViews that conform to a specific protocol, snapshot them and save the result png like it was running in an iOS X device.

Comment: @matt I edited my question to add the script

Comment: ok; that's something you would do within your app, not in a script. The script you posted doesn't do that, however, and nothing in it requires UIKit. "Check if file is a class…" doesn't make sense. Files aren't classes. Is this about a jailbroken device? You seem to be targeting the simulator, not a device anyway.

Comment: not at all. the idea is to iterate all .swift files and look for protocol implementation in the contents of the file, then instantiate it if it's has the keyword class, snapshot and save. Yeah, it's overengineering - and probably the wrong approach - and it could be easily within the app, but I don't want it to be a dependency like R.swift for instance does. Does it makes sense?

Comment: "Does it make sense" No. What does "snapshot" mean? I don't see your script making any "snapshot". Does it mean saving a png of that view as it is rendered in real life? You can't snapshot a UIView except within the context of a running app. It seems to me that this task is looking much more like a job for a UITest and the `snapshot` command. UITests are a _great_ way to cycle thru your app's interface and deliberately take snapshots that are saved for purposes of debugging, localization, etc.

Comment: plz abstract of the fact the code is not doing that - the code is an example - getting back to the topic the question is: "How swift script can import UIKit".

Comment: But I am saying that that appears to be an x-y question. You are trying to do something and _assuming_ that that is how to do it. It isn't.